# BlueScreens on my ThinkPad with Windows 7 64 Bit and a SSD (CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION, ntoskernel.exe)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ssd, bsod, ntoskrnl.exe

I'm getting BlueScreens about every five days for more than three months.

Here's an example:

> A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent
>   damage to your computer.
>
> The problem seems to be caused by the following file: ntoskrnl.exe
>
> CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION
>
> If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart
>   your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:
>
> Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
>   If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software
>   manufacturer for any Windows updates you might need.
>
> If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
>   or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
>   If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
>   your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then
>   select Safe Mode.
>
> Technical Information:
>
> *** STOP: 0x000000f4 (0x0000000000000003, 0xfffffa80065f2b30, 0xfffffa80065f2e10, 0xfffff80002f9bf40)
>
> *** ntoskrnl.exe - Address 0xfffff80002c98d00 base at 0xfffff80002c19000 DateStamp 0x4d9fdd5b

It's has always been the same BlueScreen message showing `CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION`, `0x000000f4`, and `ntoskrnl.exe`. Of course the addresses change.

My computer is a ThinkPad T400 (about 2 years old) with a SSD in it. I'm also running Windows 7 Professional 64 bit. When I bought my computer, it had a 250GByte SeaGate HDD in it, which I replaced by a 500GByte HDD by Western Digital. Last september I bought a Corsair F120 SSD and replaced the HDD by this SSD. Then I bought a LEICKE HDD adapter for the UltraBay II where I plugged in my 500GByte HDD. This configuration ran about half a year without any errors. After re-installing Windows this spring, I am getting regular BlueScreens. Sometimes my system runs for about 2 weeks without a BSOD, sometimes I get several BlueScreens a day.

The only thing that I noticed is that I'm always running Google Chrome when it happens.

Is there anyone who has made his/her own bad experiences with some of my components, or is there anybody who can tell me if it would be helpful to send my notebook to Lenovo?

Comment: You might want to analyze crash dump located at C:\windows\minidump using windbg

Answer (score 0):

.

[Drivers, Software related to drivers, Disk errors or Malware can cause this particular error.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

1. Run a chkdsk on the SSD
2. Update all your Motherboard and Video drivers
3. [Scan for Malware](http://connect.microsoft.com/systemsweeper)
4. [Run a memory diagnostic](http://www.memtest.org/), let it run overnight to stress test the memory

Comment: Ok, I'll respond later.

Comment: I ran CHKDSK on the SSD and scanned for malware with system sweeper. It did not find anything. The SSD firmware, video and other drivers are up to date. I did not update to the current BIOS version, since there is an issue with my graphics card when I install it.

Comment: Makes me wonder if the problem is the graphics card.

Comment: This ThinkPad has got on-board graphics as well as a ATI graphics card. They can be switched. The ATI graphics are having the issue with the BIOS and the integrated chip doesn’t. Maybe the problem is something with the graphics card, but I’m almost sure that the BlueScreens occur with the integrated graphics, too.

Comment: "Computers are so close to magic that it is easy to forget that they are machines. Incredibly, brain-breakingly complex machines, that record and recover millions of bits of information a second (in RAM or on your hard drive), etching down those details in the magnetic fields of microscopically small bits of matter. So much is done, so quickly, on such a small scale that quantum mechanics becomes relevant, that I'm amazed any computer ever manages to work at all, ever."...http://jeff-vogel.blogspot.com/2011/06/everything-breaks-all-time.html

Comment: Damn. I got five bluescreens this morning.

Comment: Run a memory diagnostic, let it run overnight...http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: I already did. It's not the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Corsair recently recalled that particular model for similar problems on other systems:

http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=95688

You may want to give Corsair a call and confirm if your SSD was included in that recall.

Comment: I checked my model number. It's a F120GB2. According to this blog post, only F120GB3 models are affected. Thanks for the idea. Maybe it's something like this anyway.

Comment: Ahh, you have a Series 2 drive. Unlikely to be affected but given recent issues with some SandForce controllers worth checking all the same.

Comment: Is there a way to check the sanity of my drive? I don't think CHKDSK is able to assert sanity for SSDs.

Comment: You would need a tool that can read the drive's SMART information. Try HD Tune or other suitable tool. Anything showing as outside of normal (non-green in HD Tune) might indicate a problem.

Comment: Everything is ok in HD Tune. The error scan didn't show any errors.

Comment: HD Tune: Corsair CSSD-F120GB2 Error Scan

Scanned data   : 114427 MB
Damaged Blocks : 0.0 %
Elapsed Time   : 18:07

Answer (score 0):

It says supporting only Vista 32bit.
Thus any IBM/Lenovo driver you try to install will guarantee a nice bluescreen crash.

It could be also network drivers - check if Windows Update does not have some for you

Answer (score -4):

This error arises when the hardware and software become faulty. To remove this error, check your RAM and hard drive and reinstall RAM or remove bad RAM. When this error arises on a WiFi hotspot, then it's a hardware issue with your LAN card. The last solution is a Windows change or update.

Comment: So, in a nutshell, either replace your memory, your hard drive or your network adaptor, or install a new operating system. Wow, that really nails down the solution.